# Pop-Up display in Android using alertdialog.builder

Tags: android

I am new to Android Programming. I need to display a Pop-Up message in my application which I have no clue about. I got to hear from somewhere that it can be done using alertdialog.builder, but I have no idea how to do that?

I just want to display a simple Text Message.

Can anybody please help me out regarding this with an example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a pop up that the user has to acknowledge by pressing a button, you can do something like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage("message text").setPositiveButton("OK", null).setTitle("Title").show();
```

you can leave out setTitle if you don't need it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display a simple message you're probably better off [using a `Toast`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Some Text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or, if you're doing it properly, and using a String resource:

```
Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.message_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```